# Why Private data member inherited in child class

Tags: java

I have this piece of code

```
public class Base {
    private int x=10;
     void show(){
         System.out.println(x);
     }

}


public class Child extends Base {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Child c1=new Child();
        c1.show();

    }

}
```

This piece of code is working fine and output is 10.Can anyone please
Elaborate how this private data member is access in child class..

Comment: Try `c1.x;` from `main` and you will see the compilation error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't. The `show()` method is accessed. That method of the parent then accesses the field `x`. The `show()` method has default access, which includes access by the `Child` as it is in the same package.

Comment: Are you sure the method invoked is from the parent and not from the child? I don't any thing related to parent in `Child c1=new Child();
        c1.show();`.

Comment: @BheshGurung The `show()` method is part of the parent. It is inherited by the child but it still has all the access rights of the parent. If the child had overridden the parent method it would not have had access anymore.

Comment: @BheshGurung If you would have access to override show() of course. The default mode [doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private).